# Querying User Stories under an Initiative in Rally

Tags: rally

I need to see all of the user stories under an initiative, in rally. I realize that the parent hierarchy doesn't work this way. It goes:

Initiative -> Feature -> User Story

Is it possible to query(in the rally custom list UI) user stories under an initiative?

(PortfolioItem.FormattedID = I12345)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try querying for UserStories whereby:

(Feature.Parent.FormattedID = I12345)

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you!